# How to make a semi-sticky header?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, scroll

I have a header that starts in the middle of the page.

I'd like for it to move up and past the top of the page on scroll down (with ease-out) and then come back and stay on top of the page on scroll up until the user is back to the main page, at which point the head comes back to the middle.

As of right now, i just have it ease-in to the top and stay there with:

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky-180) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>
```

css:

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

i didn't make the ease-in animation, so I'm not entirely sure how it works. But I just have it in the `column` class which has the scrolling animation applied to it, so it seems to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let speeds = {
    'slow': 0.5,
    'mid': 0.7,
    'fast': 1,
    'ss':1.75,
  };
  let noColumns = $('.column').length;
  let columns = new Array();
  for (let i = 0; i < noColumns; i++) {
    columns.push({
      columnHeight: parseInt($('.column').eq(i).css('height')),
      position: 0,
      speed: speeds[$('.column').eq(i).attr('data-speed')]
    });
  }
  let previousScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  var conHeight = parseInt($('.column').eq(0).css('height')) * 3;
  //all activate. the times x makes it keep going after we run out of original view
  $('.tall').css('height', conHeight + 'px');
  $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {

    var shift = $(this).scrollTop() - previousScroll;
    previousScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    for (var i = 0; i < noColumns; i++) {
      columns[i].position -= shift * columns[i].speed;
      $('.column').eq(i).css('top', columns[i].position + 'px');
    }
  });
});
```

i found a couple of tutorials on how to make a header that disappears on the top and then comes back when you scroll up, like this one https://codepen.io/kaemak/pen/mHyKa/, but I'm not sure how to combine it with what I have already.

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Comment: @mizurnix, it's a lot of messy divs inside divs on top of other divs X.X ... i'll try make another, more general file and post it ... but it should just be a header in a div, maybe inside another div, which scroll at different speeds for the parallax effect